# How to write a tuple of floats to the file space separated with only one call to write in python?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Lets suppose that I have a list of floats and I want to write it in a file. I am using python. I want all the elements to be space separated and I don't want to use more than one call to write function. Follwoing code illustrate writing it but it is comma separated...

```
    arr [-12.0, 1.7, -5.5, 4.0]
    f = open("data.dat","w")
    f.write(str(arr))
    f.close()
```

The list is written in the file as follows (along with commas and square brackets)

```
   [-12.0, 1.7, -5.5, 4.0]
```

I want to have following written with one call to write

```
   -12.0 1.7 -5.5 4.0
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: `[]` is a `list`, not a `tuple`. `tuple` literals are done as `(-12.0, 1.7, ...)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the elements of `arr` are not strings, you have to convert them to strings before [joining](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```
with open("data.dat","w") as f:
    f.write(' '.join(map(str,arr)))
```

PS. Since this question is tagged as `numpy`, note that you could also use `np.savetxt`:

```
np.savetxt('data.dat',(arr,),delimiter=' ',fmt='%g')
```

Comment: which is quicker for large arrays?

Comment: @polyphant: `np.savetxt` is quicker (at least on my machine) even if `arr` has only 100 elements. The speed gain (in favor of `np.savetxt`) becomes greater as the size of the array grows. To test for yourself, use [the timeit module](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/timeit.html) or  [IPython's timeit function](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/interactive/magics.html#magic-timeit).

Answer (score 2):

```
li = [-12.0, 1.7, -5.5, 4.0]     

with open("data.dat","w") as f:
    f.write(" ".join(map(str,li)))
```

**li** instead of **arr** because arrays are [this](http://docs.python.org/library/array.html#module-array) in Python

You should consider to use :

```
f.write("\t".join(map(str,li)))
```

that introduces tab instead of blank

By the way, if you want to add the data at the end of the file  replace the mode `'r'` with `'a'`, otherwise you delete all the previous data in the file if it existed one of the same name

Comment: thanks for the answer... Your answer is also correct... I accepted the one which was give earlier.